# What are files *.ko used for?

Tags: kernel-modules

The following two commands output the same thing:

```
$ modinfo iwlwifi
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
....
$ modinfo /lib/modules/3.16.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
```

What is `iwlwifi.ko` used for? What does `.ko` mean?

Is its content the installed module `iwlwifi`, or only the information about this module (similar to manpage of a program)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the module code itself. Module metadata is usually either stored inside the module `.ko` or within flat files underneath `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/`. If you want to know more about the module you're looking at you can do a `modinfo iwlwifi`

Comment: I suggest clarifying that it's the object (compiled) code, not the source code.